# Перевод многоразрядного числа в другую систему счисления.

Tags: c, c++, список

Есть двунаправленный список. Каждый элемент - цифра многоразрядного числа. Вообще не представляю, как перевести число в другую систему счисления, пока оно в списке=\

Comment: В другую систему счисления - это в предствалении такого же списка или просто в int например?

Comment: Видимо надо реализовать многоразрядную арифметику ("в столбик").

 Число это список цифр. Выполняете операции деления над двумя числами (списками), получаете третий список (остаток). Склеиваете остатки - получаете число (тоже список цифр) в искомой системе счисления.

Comment: Проще всё-таки преобразовать в вид (целое), с которым арифметика уже реализована

Comment: Ну, это если разрядность позволяет. 

Можно, конечно же (если самому программировать не охота), найти библиотеку для многоразрядной арифметики и преобразовать эти списки в требуемый формат.

Comment: "Видимо надо реализовать многоразрядную арифметику ("в столбик").
Число это список цифр. Выполняете операции деления над двумя числами (списками), получаете третий список (остаток). Склеиваете остатки - получаете число (тоже список цифр) в искомой системе счисления."

Похоже, что как-то так и надо сделать, ибо если работать как с обычным числом, получается некорректный результат.

Comment: В вашем вопросе есть несколько недоговорок:

     1) Из какой в какую систему счисления надо переводить
     2) Какой STL контейнер вы используете( не List? )

Comment: @Asen, предположим, нужно переводить в любую систему счисления из любой другой, и контейнер не из STL, а собственная реализация двусвязного списка:) Я так понимаю, ТС нужна не конкретная реализация, а скорее совет.

Answer (score 1):

Примерно так. (А возиться с реализацией арифметики в списковом представлении... Есть желание -- пожалуйста).

```
#include <list>
#include <gmpxx.h>
list<unsigned int> conv (list<unsigned int> in, int inradix, int outradix) {
    mpz_class num = 0;
    list<unsigned int> out;
    for(list<unsigned int>::iterator it=in.begin(); it != in.end(); it++) num = num * inradix + *it;
    if(num == 0) out.push_back(0);
    else while (num > 0) {
        // для ускорения можно использовать функцию, одновременно дающую и частное и остаток
        // но в gmpxx qr функций нет, надо использовать сишные из gmp
        mpz_class n1 = num % outradix;
        out.push_front(n1.get_ui());
        num /= outradix;
    }
    return out;
}
```

Comment: Так, ради интереса, почему вы решили добавлять элементы в начало списка, а не в конец?

     out.push_front(n1.get_ui());

Comment: Это младшая цифра. Если её добавлять в конец, то число получится задом наперёд, и потребуется дополнительный вызова reverse()